# Setting up the RTI DDS configuration file in ROS2

Tags: data-distribution-service, ros2, rti-dds

I am interfacing ROS2 with native RTI DDS using xml app creation i.e. means all the QoS settings are in this xml file.

Now, for the native DDS application, I can set this .xml file but how can I set a similar sort of a configuration file for a ROS2 based function ?

Comment: I suggest you to go to https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.0/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/Content/UsersManual/How_to_Load_XML_Specified_QoS_Settings.htm and have a look at https://github.com/ros2/rmw_connext/blob/e8e50e12ea4a8f48201fe6947ed1cb7df8acce22/rmw_connext_shared_cpp/src/qos.cpp to update the default configuration

Comment: @Stoogy : sorry but i still could not figure it out. Is it possible to give a bit detailed description ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you reviewed the material in: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings?  ROS2 has a limited set of options for setting QoS.

You might have more success by setting the QoS policies in your DDS application to match the settings in ROS2.  (BTW, this is a place where RTI Admin Console makes things a lot easier; it immediately reveals any QoS mismatches between the participants).

The DDS QoS settings I've used to get DDS/ROS2 interoperability include:

- If using ROS2 'Ardent':

  - use a DDS partition named "rt" (set in QoS file under `<publisher_qos>`)
- If using ROS2 'Bouncy':

  - Prefix the topic names with "rt/"
  - Suppress typeCode sending (set in QoS file under `<participant_qos><resource_limits>` the max_serialized_length for type_code and type_object == 0)
- For either release:

  - May need to include support for unbounded strings and sequences.
  - May need to include UDPv6 and disable SHMEM transports

There are not many QoS settings made in the ROS2 RMW code; the Connext libs will look for a source of user QoS settings using the normal search order ([detailed here](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.3.1/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/index.htm#UsersManual/How_to_Load_XML_Specified_QoS_Settings.htm)) - meaning you can provide your own QoS settings to the Connext libs under ROS2, using a variety of methods.  Here's what I did:

- To disable multicast in ROS2, create a file named "NDDS_DISCOVERY_PEERS" in a directory from which your ROS2 application(s) will be launched (directory where the ros2 command is entered and run).  Place in this file a list of the initial peers for discovery (make sure to exclude multicast and shmem) format as detailed [here](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.3.1/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/index.htm#UsersManual/NDDS_DISCOVERY_PEERS_File_Format.htm).

  - My file had: localhost,192.168.1.44
- For other QoS settings, place in the same directory as above a "USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml" file containing the QoS settings you'd like to use in ROS2.   These settings will affect the ROS2 applications launched from that directory.

Comment: Yes I already read the ROS supported QoS settings. The problem is that how do I let ROS2 know, not to use Multicasting or shared memory ?  I have already applied these settings to the native DDS application but does this mean that i do not need to implement on the ROS2 side ? i.e. setting up in only one participant is sufficient ?

Comment: this was the exact answer i was looking for. Thank you. I will try this out and come back to you again :)